# How to run percentage computations with data from two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an 'Orders' table and a 'Records' table.
Orders table has the following columns:

```
order_id       order_date        seller       order_price
```

Records table has the following columns:

```
order_id        record_created_at         record_log
```

record_log shows whether an order was 'approved' or 'declined' and I'm trying to find out what percentage of orders was approved (# of approved orders/total # of orders) and what percentage of order amount in dollars was approved ($ of approved orders/total $ of orders) per each seller.

I'm using the query below for percentage of orders approved in quantity:

```
(
        SELECT COUNT(raw_log = 'order approved')/COUNT(*)
        FROM logs_table l
        WHERE l.order_id = o.order_id
    ) AS approval_rate_by_count
```

It's giving me mixed results, as some numbers are correct and some aren't.
I'm also not sure how to use this same logic for getting percentage of order approved in dollar amounts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` over the condition `raw_log = 'order approved'`:

```
SELECT SUM(raw_log = 'order approved')/COUNT(*)
FROM logs_table
```

In mysql, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so *summing* a condition counts how many times it was `true`.

Comment: tried that and it gives me ridiculously large numbers instead of a proportion between 0 and 1.

Comment: it's impossible to return more than  `1.0`

Comment: sorry you're right, I had to fix some other part in my code. thanks for that. how would I do the same thing but for order price. like if the total order amount was $1000 and $700 got approved, how would I compute that proportion in the context of above two tables?

Comment: That's a different question: You should ask it in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).